# How can I improve my code, so that I can find the word in a text file with most "z" characters in it?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, count, readlines

So I'm just learning Python and programming for the first time, and I have this piece of code that I'm having some issues with.

I have a function that is supposed to return the word from a text file named 'dictionary.txt' that contains the most "z" characters. The code goes as follows;

[Function to find the word with the most "z" characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2bGd.png)

However, when I print the return statement I just get "A" as an answer, which indicates that all the values or words in the text file haven't been looped properly, since it just stops looping after the first value in the text file, which is "A".

Any idea as to how I can adjust the coding, so that all words are accounted for in the 'dictionary.txt' file, and the word with the most "z" characters can be found?

Much appreciated!

/before_elijah

Comment: Please paste your code into the question as text instead of an image.

Comment: First of all do not post images of code, post the actual code. secondly, your conditional is backwards on line 17

Comment: @Nullman Ahh sorry, just learning to use stackoverflow

But hey you're right, thanks for the help:)